# Three.js THREE.DeviceOrientationControls is not a constructor

Tags: constructor, three.js, device-orientation

I have a problem with ThreeJS giving me this error message. I included all the necessary ThreeJS files but still this message appears. My intention is to have a mobile device navigating with DeviceOrientationControl.js. Mousemove works very well, but I can't get this to work. Any ideas?

```
Uncaught TypeError: THREE.DeviceOrientationControls is not a constructor
    at init ((index):201)
    at (index):193
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSCrF.png)

```
<script type="module">

        import * as THREE from '/bftest/three/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from '/bftest/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from '/bftest/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import {DeviceOrientationControls} from '/bftest/three/examples/jsm/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js'; 

    
     var camera, scene, renderer, stats, controls, windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,
        mouseX = 0,
        mouseY = 0;


    
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; 

  var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


    init();
    animate();




    function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
        controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 8);
        scene = new THREE.Scene();



var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 5);
directionalLight.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1);
directionalLight.position.multiplyScalar(10);
scene.add(directionalLight);
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = -20;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 20;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 20;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -20;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 200;
directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

            var spotLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xff4000 );
    spotLight1.position.set( -15, 3, -4 );
    spotLight1.target.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
    spotLight1.intensity = 1.2;
    spotLight1.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
 
    spotLight1.shadowcameranear = 0;
    spotLight1.shadowcamerafar = 15;
 
    spotLight1.shadowcameraleft = -5;
    spotLight1.shadowcameraright = 5;
    spotLight1.shadowcameratop = 5;
    spotLight1.shadowcamerabottom = -5;
    spotLight1.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( spotLight1 );

            var spotLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xff0aea );
    spotLight2.position.set( 15, 3, -4 );
    spotLight2.target.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
    spotLight2.intensity = 1.2;
    spotLight2.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( spotLight2 );

var hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff,0x000000, .5)
  
    var shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8f16, .4);
shadowLight.position.set(50, 0, 22);
shadowLight.target.position.set(50, 50, 0);
shadowLight.rotation.set(Math.PI / -2, 0, 0);
shadowLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;       
shadowLight.shadow.camera.far = 5000;      
shadowLight.shadow.camera.left = -500;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -500;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.right = 500;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.top = 500;
scene.add(shadowLight);
  
  var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfff150, .25);
    light2.position.set(-600, 350, 350);

  
  var light3 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfff150, .15);
    light3.position.set(0, -250, 300);


    scene.add(hemisphereLight);  
    scene.add(shadowLight);


              const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    gltfLoader.load('./3D/Bobby.glb', (gltf) => {
      const root = gltf.scene;
      
      root.rotateY(-89.55);

      root.position.set(0, -0.7, 0);
      root.castShadow = true; 
gltf.scene.traverse(function(node) {
    if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      node.castShadow = true;
    }
  });





            scene.add(root);//default is false

      // compute the box that contains all the stuff
      // from root and below
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);

      const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
      const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

      // set the camera to frame the box
      frameArea(boxSize * 0.7, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);

      box.castShadow = true;


      // update the Trackball controls to handle the new size
      controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
      controls.target.copy(boxCenter);



    });


        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas: document.querySelector('canvas'), alpha: true, });
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
   
}



function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
        mouseX = - (event.clientX - windowHalfX) /150;
        mouseY = - (event.clientY - windowHalfY) /150;
    }

    


    function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        render(scene,camera);

    }

function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}


    function render() {
          
        camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x)*0.9;
        camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y)*0.9;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When importing examples files like  `DeviceOrientationControls` via ES6 modules, using the `THREE` namespace is not necessary anymore. So instead of

```
controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
```

use

```
controls = new DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
```

Comment: Good point! There is no error now, yet it still doesn't work (can only test on iOS at the moment). The object doesn't move. How can I make it work the same way as the mouse movements?

I'm referring to this example below in means of general functionality: https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html
Here my iPhone is asking for permission and the control works. In my code it doesn't still.

Comment: It seems that you code does not implement the approach from the example where a user action is requested before the setup happens. This is required before `DeviceOrientationControls` can be used.

Comment: I got OrbitControls to work. The issue was the bounding box which centered my object around it's center. However now the object is off center and I can't adjust it properly. Is there a way to make Orbit Controls work with a bounding box?

Comment: Better to ask a new question for this.

Comment: Doing that now. Thanks!